# convert ASP page to Image (jpg, png...)

Tags: css, image, asp-classic, dreamweaver

I would like to convert my classic asp page how contains label controls with positioning style to image with JPG or png format then sending them with CDO.

I used dreamwaver for this task, anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You're question is really vague, but if you're talking about allowing a webpage to take a screenshot of itself, follow this article: http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/?p=304

If you have any experience this should be extremely easy to follow. The example shows a small bit of PHP, but it should easily be convertible to Classic ASP.

... But if this question is less complicated than I assumed...

[Taking a screenshot on Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/take-screen-capture-print-screen#take-screen-capture-print-screen=windows-8)

On Mac: Command + Shift + 3